# Detecting if it is the last instance of the application c#

Tags: c#, .net, multiple-instances

I have program of which i have to launch multiple instances.

However i have to perform some actions if the present instance is the last instance.

Is there any way to do so ? If yes then how do i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(Process.GetProcessesByName("yourprogram").Length == 0)
{
    // It's the only instance!
}
```

Comment: OP needs > to launch multiple instances. How your code will help him?

Comment: @VMAtm The question title is misleading, and judging from the accepted answer I think we understood what the OP really wanted, no need for downvoting answers.

Comment: @ChrisBint Thanks, and +1 to you as you beat me by a minute, I need to type faster :)

Comment: @VMAtm Apologies, your comment just seemed a bit negative.

Comment: @Bali C That is because I think it woudn't be an answer. But live is strange sometimes :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way is probably to count the number of running processes

```
var count = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get a list of the processes with the same name as the current and act accordingly;

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Name.of.process.here");
if(processes.Length == 1)
```

Comment: OP needs > to launch multiple instances. How your code will help him?

Comment: @VMAtm No, the OP needs to know if the current instance is the last instance.

Answer (score 0):

In CLR via C# book by Jeffrey Richter it was an example to use `Semaphore` class for this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading; 

public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        bool created; 

        using(new Semaphore(0, 1, "SomeUniqueStringIdentifyingMyApp", out created)) {
            if(created) {
                //This thread created kernel object so no other instance of this app must be running
            } else {
                //This thread opens existing kernel object with the same string name which means 
                //that another instance of this app must be running. 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems little like overkill, attempting to create a new instance just to see if one already exists.

Comment: OP DO want to >i have to launch multiple instances. How this can help him?

Comment: Yep, for multiple instances it won't work. I think i misunderstood question in the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that all other answerers don't order application instances.

How do you want to order your applications? By the start time? If so, you can use [Isolated storage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6535/Isolated-Storage-in-NET-to-store-application-data) for your code, storing there a date of last start of your application instance, and compare it with start date for this current instance (make a static property in your application). See too: [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dzh4ws.aspx).

If you don't want to order your applications, just use the [Process.GetProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname.aspx), simply passing there a name for your application.

Note that debug mode process name differs from release mode process name